# HTML & CSS best practices for this customer checklist control?

Tags: html, css

**HTML & CSS**

```css
.route-checklist {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.route-checklist.uniform {
  width: 1000px;
}

.route-checklist:not(.uniform) {
  justify-content: center;
}

.customer-checklist {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.route-checklist.uniform > .customer-checklist {
  min-width: 400px;
}

.route-checklist:not(.uniform) > .customer-checklist {
  text-align: center;
}

.customer-checklist .customer {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.route-checklist.uniform > .customer-checklist .customer {
  width: 300px;
  /* display: inline-block; */
}

.checkin-checklist {
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.route-checklist.uniform .checkin-checklist {
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.route-checklist:not(.uniform) .checkin-checklist {
  display: flex;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
}

.checklist-item {
  width: 125px;
  text-align: left;
}

.checklist-item.large {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Setup #1 - Solo version -->
<h2>Solo Version</h2>
<p>Appears on the pages of each link.</p>

<div class="route-checklist">
  <div id="1" class="customer-checklist">
    <span class="customer">Test Customer #1</span>
    <div class="checkin-checklist">

      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="truck stock-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="truck stock-link" href="#truckstock/18458">Truck Stock</a>
      </div>
      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="deliveries-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="deliveries-link" href="#deliveries/18458">Deliveries</a>
      </div>

      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="returns-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="returns-link" href="#returns/18458">Returns</a>
      </div>

      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="onhands-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="onhands-link" href="#onhands/18458">OnHands</a>
      </div>

      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="buybacks-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="buybacks-link" href="#buybacks/18458">BuyBacks</a>
      </div>

      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="samples-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="samples-link" href="#samples/18458">Samples</a>
      </div>

      <div class="checklist-item large">
        <a class="back-link" href="#">Back to List</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Setup #2: "uniform" aka List version -->
<h2>List Version</h2>
<p>This is the checklist that the "Back to List" link refers.</p>

<div class="route-checklist uniform">
  <div id="1" class="customer-checklist">
    <span class="customer">Test Customer #1</span>
    <div class="checkin-checklist">

      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="truck stock-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="truck stock-link" href="#truckstock/18458">Truck Stock</a>
      </div>
      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="deliveries-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="deliveries-link" href="#deliveries/18458">Deliveries</a>
      </div>

      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="returns-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="returns-link" href="#returns/18458">Returns</a>
      </div>

      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="onhands-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="onhands-link" href="#onhands/18458">OnHands</a>
      </div>

      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="buybacks-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="buybacks-link" href="#buybacks/18458">BuyBacks</a>
      </div>

      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="samples-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="samples-link" href="#samples/18458">Samples</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="customer-checklist">
    <span class="customer">Test Customer #2</span>
    <div class="checkin-checklist">

      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="truck stock-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="truck stock-link" href="#truckstock/18459">Truck Stock</a>
      </div>
      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="deliveries-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="deliveries-link" href="#deliveries/18459">Deliveries</a>
      </div>

      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="returns-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="returns-link" href="#returns/18459">Returns</a>
      </div>

      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="onhands-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="onhands-link" href="#onhands/18459">OnHands</a>
      </div>

      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="buybacks-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="buybacks-link" href="#buybacks/18459">BuyBacks</a>
      </div>

      <div class="checklist-item ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="samples-checkbox check-in-checkbox" disabled="disabled">
        <a class="samples-link" href="#samples/18459">Samples</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- **List Style** - Made so that more customer checklists are visible on the page at one time.
- **Solo Style** - Made so that it fits in the empty space next to another control that is on every page linked by the control.

**Concerns**

I'm not really worried about the visuals of the site, so much as

- Are there more efficient ways to accomplish these styles?
- Am I missing some best practices I'm not aware of?

*Note - In case it matters I have to support IE11, Chrome, and Safari (iPad).*